# Converting numeric to currency within model?

Tags: ruby, currency

I'm generating invoice PDFs on the fly, and using my model to calculate the totals. For example:

```
 def cost
    jobs.inject(0) do |sum, job|      
      sum + job.cost
    end
  end
```

When generating my invoice I want the following in currency:

```
 pdf.text "Invoice Total: $#{number_to_currency(cost)}"
```

But when I attempt to use the number_to_currency helper in order to display the calculated values as currency, I get errors.  Any advice on how/where to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Please... give us some sample values you used and the error message, otherwise we have no way to reproduce and help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling the code from within your model, you will need to include the helper as they are not included in ActiveRecord::Base.

So, you might have something like this in your model code:

```
has_many :jobs

include ActionView::Helpers

def cost
  jobs.inject(0) do |sum, job|      
    sum + job.cost
  end
end

def generate_pdf
  ...

 pdf.text "Invoice Total: $#{number_to_currency(cost)}"
end
```